# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting

Crashes on:

```
<?php 
    $date = "13-06-2015 23:45:52";
    echo Datetime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s',  $date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); 
?>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on boolean

But with other dates works well:

```
<?php 
    $date = "10.06.2015 09:25:52";
    echo Datetime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s',  $date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
?>
```

Wrong format?

Comment: Neither one actually work

Comment: $date = "10.06.2015 09:25:52";
    echo Datetime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); -works

Comment: $date = "13-06-2015 23:45:52";
    echo Datetime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s',$date  )->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); - no working anyway

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Neither example work as you have multiple errors:

1. You forgot your second parameter to `Datetime::createFromFormat()`
2. `h:i:s` should be `H:i:s`
3. Your date in the second example is separated by a `.` not a `-`

Fixes:

```
<?php 
    $date = "13-06-2015 23:45:52";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); 

    $date = "10.06.2015 09:25:52";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: 2. `h:i:s` should be `H:i:s`  - that fixed my problem, `h` - 12-hour format. Thanks

Comment: Also, this is `DateTime` and not `Datetime`

Answer (score 13):

In my case I was getting this error because I was using `microtime(true)` as input:

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
```

In the specific moments where `microtime` returns a float with only zeros as decimals, this error appeared.

So I had to verify if its decimals and add a decimal part:

```
$aux = microtime(true);
$decimais = $aux - floor($aux);
if($decimais<=10e-5) $aux += 0.1; 
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $aux);
```

**EDIT**:

Due to floating point precision sometimes floor brings an incorret floor, so I had to use a more straight forward approach:

```
$aux =  microtime(true);
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $aux);        
if (is_bool($now)) $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $aux += 0.001);
```

Comment: or you could check if it is not a decimal and use 'U'

Comment: I came across same problem/error. I found this answer and investigated bit more. Fact: second parameter for `DateTime::createFromFormat` is expected to be a `string`. My final solution: `$now= DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 6, '.', ''))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO')`

Comment: PHP 7.1+ DateTime constructor includes microseconds. I used:

`$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u P");`

Answer (score 4):

While others try to get this question answered with a specific use case, I think it's time to wrap it up with a general answer.

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in path/to/source/code/file.php

When this exception error is raised, it's because the `format()` function gets a bad date format string. So, try to check the parameter according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#format

Answer (score 1):

John Conde's answer is correct. If we forget the mistakes, the error occurs because the supplied input doesn't mach the format string.

Example:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('D M j h:i:s e Y','Fri Nov  4 12:59:59 UTC 2022');
```

will return a DateTime object while following will return `false`.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('D M j h:i:s e Y','Fri Nov  4 13:00:01 UTC 2022');
```

The culprit is the letter `'h'` of the format string `'D M j h:i:s e Y'`. For 24 hour format, which 13:00:01 is, you have to use the upper case `'H'`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), you can see the difference.

**h**: 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

**H**: 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I sent an empty value from the input field and get's error

solution:

```
if ($this->input->post('date_fo_return') != "") {
        $date_fo_return = $this->input->post('date_fo_return');
    $date_fo_return2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_fo_return);
    $data['date_fo_return'] = $date_fo_return2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you look at this function `Datetime::createFromFormat`, you will find that function has 2 possible return values, they are `DateTime` object and `false`.

That fatal error happened because you call function `format` on `false` value which is invalid.

So you should check for return value first, then continue the process appropriately. Not only for this case (datetime), but also for another functions that have multiple possible return values.