# PHP DateTime: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php

I am trying to use the DateTime class to see if a certain time has passed or not. However when using the DateTime class it fails...

This is my string which I get from my database:

```
$timeToCheck = $users[$i]["lastLoggedIn"] . " " . $users[$i]["lastTimeOn"];
```

An example for this would be: 2016-03-09 01:32:44

Then I use the following:

```
$dbTimeStamp = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeToCheck);

$timeStamp = new DateTime($dbTimeStamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$timeLimit = $timeStamp->add(new DateInterval("PT24H"));

$timeNow = new DateTime();
```

I receive the following error:  Call to a member function format() on boolean on `$timeStamp = new DateTime($dbTimeStamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

The date format in the database is the same as the format I am trying to create and for example would be 2016-03-09 01:32:44

I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ["Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure."](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues).

Comment: So, what's the value of `$timeToCheck`?

Comment: It would be 2016-03-09 01:32:44 for example. I did put one in but probably should of put it after I showed the code for `$timeToCheck`...

Comment: If that's the value then why are you using `strtotime()`?

Comment: Testing if it made any difference, forgot to take it out as it didn't. I also tried `$dbTimeStamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeToCheck);` but did not work.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744984/ it shows a good example.

Comment: I tried using `$dbTimeStamp = Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeToCheck)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and I get Call to a member function format() on string on `$timeStamp = new DateTime($dbTimeStamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));` now.

Comment: Look, the error is telling you what's wrong. `$dbTimeStamp` is `false`. So it's not able to convert your string. You need to check for a failed time conversion

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting `$timeToCheck` to `$timeToCheck = "2016-08-21 01:22:18";` and I did not receive the error that I was getting.

So as my two sources to create my date and time string were separate in the database by date and time, I changed it so it updated this all in one string and now it works.

I used the following:

```
$dateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```