# PHP Fatal Error Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

> **Fatal:** Call to a member function format() on boolean

How can I show the date in current language?

```
$date = 1496102399;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y',"@$date");
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

I want the date to be translatable when using this date format: `j F Y` How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your `$end_date` is uninitialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30744943/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this, there are few problems in your code.

**Problems:**

> **1.** `$end_date` is not initialized. just changing this will also not work. [check here](https://eval.in/806198)
>
> **2.** `DateTime::createFromFormat` expects second parameter to be time string (like this `15-Feb-2009`) `not timestamp`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/806124)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$unixtimestamp = 1496102399;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($unixtimestamp);
echo $end_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For displaying the date in `Deutsch` language you can use this, prerequisites are listed below of this code doesn't work.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$loc=setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE');
echo strftime('%d %B %Y',1496102399);
```

> **1.** `locale -a` Listing all locale's present on your system, make sure `de_DE`,`de_DE.iso88591`,`de_DE.utf8` these locale's are present on your system
>
> **2.** `locale-gen de_DE`
>
> **3.** `dpkg-reconfigure locales` reconfigure locales

Comment: You could explain why this is the proper way.

Comment: @SahilGulati how can I convert the date format to j F Y format ?

Comment: @Himani For that change this `$date->format('Y-m-d');` to `$date->format('j F Y');` in my code..

Comment: Thanks @SahilGulati Please, can you tell me how can I make these dynamic, mean display on the basis of language selected?

Comment: @Himani what you want to be dynamic on the basis of language?

Comment: I want to display date. For eg: if the user has selected Deutsch language, should see the date 23 mei 2017 and if the language is english, then 23 may 2017

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145254/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-himani).

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has inbuilt function date_i18n() to get the date in localized format.

You can try below code:

```html
echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i:s)", strtotime('2017-05-27 16:08:01')) ;
```