# Call to a member function format() on boolean in PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

My question possibly may be a duplicate from this question:

[PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744943/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-boolean)

But I'm sure that my question is not a duplicate.

I have a problem with try to save records in datetime format.

The error is the following:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \
>
> FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>
> Call to a member function format() on boolean

**1° record**

Columns date_start and date_end respectively

court_id = 1 - NAME= TENNIS

**`2018-10-05 10:00:00`** - **`2018-10-05 11:00:00`** works perfectly. It's save without problems

Then I try to save another record in my table.

The same columns respectively.

**2° Record**

court_id = 1 - NAME = TENNIS

**`2018-10-05 12:00:00`** - **`2018-10-05 13:00:00`** not work, but it's work if the day is different for example `2018-10-06`.

The dates are similar and court_id are the same, the only difference between the record 1 and 2 are the hours.

This is my function `store()`

```
public function store(Request $request){


    $hours = new HoursNew();

    try {


        $hours->id = $request->id;

        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i', $request->date_start);
        $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i', $request->date_end);


        //THIS LINE SHOW ME AS AN ERROR
        $hours->date_start = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        $hours->date_end = $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        $hours->estate_hour_id = $request->estate_hour_id;
        $hours->court_id = $request->court_id;
        $hours->save();

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Whoops! We have some problems');

         return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');

    }
        Session::flash('message', "It's OK");
        return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');
}
```

Why I get this error, when I try to save the same dates for the same courts (court_id) but differents hours.

Comment: `$request->date_start` doesn't appear to be following the format `Y-m-d\Th:i`. Can you add to your question exactly what `$request->date_start` looks like?

Comment: can you dump `$request->date_start` ? you're getting error because `DateTime` class not working well, it returns boolean

Comment: Another possible issue with the format `Y-m-d\Th:i` which you may stumble upon later is since it's a lower-case `h`, and there's nothing in here to tell AM or PM, this function will not be able to parse anything in the `PM`.  Actually this appears to be your issue.

Comment: @user3158900. Possibly, but not 100% true. I said some examples, but If i want to add a record that says: date_start = `2018-10-06 15:00:00`, date_end `2018-10-06 16:00:00` works perfectly. Independently that is the same court_id or another court_id, this is the reason, I think that AM or PM is not influential.

Comment: Please provide samples of the *raw* input data for the two dates. There will be something about it that is causing the *createFromFormat* function to return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

`DateTime::createFromFormat()` returns false on failure. Since the hour goes from <= 12 to 13 in your example, that indicates to me that the "h" should be capitalized.

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $request->date_start);`

Comment: No problem! Please upvote  user3158900's comment. He had the right answer as well. "h" only accepts hours 1-12, which means it has no concept of AM/PM.