# Php bug related to date

Tags: php

when i edit the data and after the submission of that form, i got an error like

> ERROR - 2019-05-19 12:40:26 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Call to a member function format() on boolean 
>   please help me out of this....

i followed this but its not working [Call to a member function format() on boolean in PHP LARAVEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635804/call-to-a-member-function-format-on-boolean-in-php-laravel)

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date . ' ' . $time);
$created_at = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$record = ['created_at' => $created_at,];
```

Comment: What is `$date` and `$time`? Probably doesn't match your format.

Comment: why don't you give a try to `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `$date` or `$time` string(s) you are trying to pass into `DateTime::createFromFormat`. They should look similar to the following to work properly:

```
$date = "15/05/2019";
$time = "10:28:33";

$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date . ' ' . $time);
$created_at = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$record = ['created_at' => $created_at,];

print_r($record);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [created_at] => 2019-05-15 10:28:33
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains it all quite detailed.

**ERROR - 2019-05-19 12:40:26**

Meaning the input is in format `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`

But your code says `'d/m/Y H:i:s'`.

Either your $date variable is wrong or your code is wrong.
Most likely your code should be with format: `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`